# PyCharm just closing after executing graphics.GraphWin()?

Tags: python, pycharm

Hi everyone:) I'm new to the python and would be glad if you help. I need to draw something, so I installed graphics.py library (using PyCharm). The package was successfully installed. Then I tried to execute next code:

```py
import graphics

win = graphics.GraphWin('something', 400, 400)
```

Pycharm is closing immediately and everything is closing. Mac just go back to the login screen.

What could be the reason ? 
I tried to do the same via terminal - same result.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remain your new created graphics.GraphWin, use the **mainloop** method.

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin('Window',400,400)

win.mainloop()
```

However, if the Pycharm still being closed, my assumption is maybe your mac has a special policy that prevents running certain processes.

Another thing that could be a problem is you trying to run a Win package in MAC computer.

Notice how the method is called Graph**Win**.

Try to Execute a different package to create some Graphical User Interface like **Tkinter**

```
from tkinter import *
root.geometry('400x400')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Both methods haven't worked. I thought  - maybe something wrong with interpreter (I use anaconda ). I downloaded Python from official site - and try to execute code (from tkinter...etc) via another IDLE with the new interpreter and it worked. The window has displayed. I will try to change an interpreter in Pycharm preferences ..will see

Comment: Good luck.
There are lots of documentations on setting python interpreter out there.